# Passing json to php and updating mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to pass image coordinates via json to a php file that should update the database.
I have this in jquery:

```
var coords=[];  
var coord = $(this).position();  
var item = { coordTop:  coord.top, coordLeft: coord.left  };  
coords.push(item);  
var order = { coords: coords };  
$.ajax({   
    type: "POST",
    data : +$.toJSON(order), 
    url: "updatecoords.php",   
    success: function(response){
        $("#respond").html('<div class="success">X and Y Coordinates 
            Saved</div>').hide().fadeIn(1000);  
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            $('#respond').fadeOut(1000); 
        }, 2000);  
    }
});
```

This is what updatecoords.php looks like:

```
<?php

$db = Loader::db(); 

$data = json_decode($_POST['data']); 
foreach($data->coords as $item) {  

    $coord_X = preg_replace('/[^\d\s]/', '', $item->coordTop);  
    $coord_Y = preg_replace('/[^\d\s]/', '', $item->coordLeft);  

    $x_coord = mysql_real_escape_string($coord_X); 
    $y_coord = mysql_real_escape_string($coord_Y);

    $db->Execute("UPDATE coords SET x_pos = '$x_coord', y_pos = '$y_coord'");
}  

?>
```

The success message shows from the javascript however nothing gets updated in the database?
Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have any records? Right now your query looks like it should update all the records in the table. Also, where is `Loader` coming from?

Comment: If I manually set the rows then they are called fine like this:

`$db= Loader::db(); 
$posimg = $img->getFileID(); 
$get_coords = $db->Execute("SELECT * FROM coords WHERE id = '$posimg'"); 
while ($row = $get_coords->FetchRow()) { 
$x = $row['x_pos']; 
$y = $row['y_pos']; 
}`

But I can't get the rows to update using the coordinates sent via JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You have a + before $.toJSON. Meaning that the json string it returns will be converted to an integer - probably 0 or NaN.

Comment: It would need to be an integer as I'm calling it like so:

`$x = $row['x_pos']; 
$y = $row['y_pos']`

`<div style="left:'.$x.'px; top:'.$y.'px;">

Comment: No, the JSON should be a string. It looks something like {"coords":{...}}. Adding + before it destroys the entire string and makes it NaN. If you need integers, parseInt each coordinate before building the item/coords objects or let php cast them to integers.

Answer (score 0):

Alex is right, but you can also take the quotes out from the preg_replace pattern. PHP naturally uses /.../ slashes to "quote" a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for the help! unfortunately that didn't do the trick :(

Comment: You have no WHERE clause in your UPDATE statement. Did you intend to update all rows of the table?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  UPDATE coords SET x_pos = '".$x_coord."', y_pos = '".$y_coord."'
```

and look here how to use [toJSON](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tojson.asp)

EDIT :

try this

```
 $.ajax({   
type: "POST",
data : { coordTop:  coord.top, coordLeft: coord.left ,coords: coords },
```

and in second code do this

```
   $data = json_decode($_POST['data']); 
   $coordTop = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['coordTop']);
   $coordLeft = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['coordLeft']);
   $coords = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['coords']);
  foreach(.........
  .....
  .....
```

and then use those variables  $coordTop , $coordLeft , $coords

Comment: Thanks for the advice but no joy with this I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help but this seemed to do the trick....

In javascript:

```
$.post('updatecoords.php', 'data='+$.toJSON(order), function(response){ alert (response + mydata);
```

In Updatecoords.php:

```
$data = json_decode(stripcslashes($_POST['data']));
```